# Creating an Apple Script to change "Show as Wallpaper" option in "Screen Saver" pane

Tags: macos, applescript, script, automation, settings

I am working on a project, and it requires toggling the "Show as Wallpaper" option to True automatically. I've tried using my limited knowledge of Applescript and looking it up, but to no avail. I've also been looking around `defaults read` but to no avail. It would be a great help if someone was to point me in the right direction towards changing this option.

Thank you!

Jack

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Applescript you've already tried, and the `defaults` command you've tried. You'll have more chance of someone providing an answer.